# style text based on the context of the text in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I wondering is there is a way to style text in d3 based on the context of the text itself?

I have this chunk of d3 code that loop through a list of items and append them to the DOM on mouseover, so the list is updating a lot as the mouse moves along the chart. I'd like to color the p tag with the class coeff-direction as red or green based on the text inside saying "Avoid" or "Target" but what I have currently only colors everything red? Is there anyway to appropriately access the text so my condition will work?

```
    d.features.forEach(function(m){
      d3.select("#showdata")
        .style("display", null)
        .append("p")
        .attr("class", "coeff-direction")
        .text(m.coeffDirection + ' ')
        .style("color", function(d) {
          if ("Avoid") {
            return "red"
          } else {
            return "Green"
          }
        })
        .append("span")
        .attr("class", 'feature-description')
        .text(m.featureDescription)
    })
```

Here is a JSFiddle with all the code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hamlinkn/yaarof85/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that nothing is getting passed in the color function. You just need to check against the same variable that you are using the set the text - `m.coeffDirection`. So your if block needs to be replaced with:

```
          if (m.coeffDirection === "Avoid") {
            return "red"
          } else {
            return "Green"
          }
```

Find a working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yaarof85/8/).

Answer (score 0):

Your code only ever evaluates to true, as the string "Avoid" is always true.

```
if ("Avoid") {
   return "red"
} else {
   return "Green"
}
```

Perhaps you meant to check the argument `d` for `d === "Avoid"` ?

Example:

```
if (d === "Avoid") {
   return "red";
} else {
   return "green";
}
```

Comment: From what you've provided, I can't tell what you're passing in as the argument.

Comment: Ok @AndrueAnderson I put up a JSFiddle for you look at.